# Ng-repeat is not showing my items in a Flask application.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask, angularjs-ng-repeat

ng-repeat crashes my code. When I use `{{item.Title}}` my app dies.
When I use `{{ item }}` my app runs, I get blanks inside HTML tags.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="App"  > 

            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

                <div ng-repeat="item in resources" >  

                 <p> {{ item }}  </p> 

                </div> 
        </div>  
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.resources =  [
                      {
                        "Category":"A",
                        "Topic":"U",
                        "Age":"2",
                        "Title":"13"
                      },
                      {
                        "Category":"A",
                        "Topic":"U",
                        "Age":"3",
                        "Title":"12"
                      }
                      ]
```

The controller code is below:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['$http']);
console.log(989)


App.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
    function($scope, $http) {
        console.log(123456789876543456789)      
        $http.get('../static/js/data.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.resources = data;

// console.log($scope)
// console.log($scope.resources)
      });
}]);
```

This is a Flask application using partials... The source of problem is double curlies. Solved!

Comment: nothing shown would do that or aren't showing us enough of the app  Sounds like you have some sort of scope problem. Create a demo that replicates issue

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the developer console (or whatever the browser's console)?

Comment: Please show more code, when controller and module are created?

Comment: Can you show us the entire code for the controller?

Comment: and what the hell is in that data.json file? I assume error is in invalid json syntax.

Comment: Can you reproduce your error in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
{% raw %}

item.Title

{% endraw %}
```

Comment: What does raw mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind using {{ resources.title }}

Comment: `title` is an attribute of the `item`. Look at his `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that you named 'item in resources' in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

I have created JS fiddle and working as expected please have a look at my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/tpxrmrx2/)

```
angular.module("App", []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.resources = [{
        "Category": "A",
            "Topic": "U",
            "Age": "2",
            "Title": "13"
    }, {
        "Category": "A",
            "Topic": "U",
            "Age": "3",
            "Title": "12"
    }]
});
```

.

```
$http.get('../static/js/data.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.resources = data;
            $scope.$apply();
      });
```

Comment: I know the above should work.. I had it working before.. I am using Flask with partials. The above code is only on this partial. I load angular only on this partial. 'item' is seen,  but using its properties causes a blow up. I have tried to stringify the data object with no benefit.

Comment: Did you try $scope.$apply() ?

Comment: yes, its not $apply...The items get applied, but the 'p' tag is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', 
      function($scope, $http) {   
        $http.get('../static/js/data.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.resources = data;
      }); 
});
```

The data.json file content looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Category":"A",
        "Topic":"U",
        "Age":"2",
        "Title":"13"
    },
    {
        "Category":"A",
        "Topic":"U",
        "Age":"3",
        "Title":"12"
    }
]
```

Comment: How does your data.json file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Item is an object and p tag wants to show a string. Try with

```
<p>{{item.title}}</p>
```